# Na/NaN/Inf error in DepmixS4 package while fitting HMM in R

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

I am running HMM on physicians' prescription data and trying to identify hidden states related to every physician.
I am getting below error for most of the physicians.
fm is fitted model.

```
   mod <- depmix(response = diff ~ 1, data = t, nstates = states, 
                transition = ~ (tot_calls)+(tot_samples)
   fm <- fit(mod, verbose = F)
```

Error that I am getting-

```
object 'fm' not found<simpleError in lm.wfit(x = as.matrix(object@x[!nas,]), 
y = as.matrix(object@y[!nas,]), w = w[!nas]): NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'>
```

Please suggest how can i avoid this error. Please let me know if any more information can make this question more clear.